# How to iterate over QSqlTableModel and export to .csv

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel

I'm trying to export data from SQlite3 database to .csv, using pyqt5, QSqlTableModel and csv. I can export all the data from my database,  I'm trying to export only the selected rows from QSqlTableModel, I really liked to mess around QSqlTableModel class, the write/read interaction is really amazing.

I got to this stage by following a couple of examples from others users.

```
    def on_Click(self):
    with open("cadastro.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        if self.tableView.selectionModel().hasSelection():
            names = []
            rows = self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
            for i in rows:
                name = self.tableView.model().index(i.row(), i.column()).data()
                names.append(name)
                print(name)
            csvwriter.writerow(
                ['id', 'instituicao', 'crianca', 'data_de_nascimento', 'manequim', 'calcado', 'responsavel'])
            csvwriter.writerow(names)
            # csvwriter.writerows(map(lambda x: [x], names))
            # print(i.row())
        else:
            print('No row selected!')
```

So I'm trying to select rows and save that selection on a csv file like that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWudy.png)

The result is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trzi3.png)

and I need something like that :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QclIO.png)

Also here is the rest of the code.

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("bolsa_natal.db")
        self.db.open()
        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.initializedModel()

        self.tableView = QTableView()

        # turn off row numbers
        self.tableView.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        # turn off horizontal headers
        # self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)

        self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.tableView.resizeRowsToContents()

        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.source_model = self.model
        # self.initializedModel()
        self.proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel(self.source_model)
        self.searchcommands = QLineEdit("")
        self.searchcommands.setObjectName(u"searchcommands")
        self.searchcommands.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.buttonCadastro = QPushButton('to .csv', self)
        self.buttonCadastro.clicked.connect(self.exportCadastro)

        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.source_model)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.proxy_model)

        # hide columns from the maintableview
        # self.tableView.hideColumn(0)
        # self.tableView.hideColumn(3)
        # self.tableView.hideColumn(4)
        # self.tableView.hideColumn(5)
        # self.tableView.hideColumn(6)
        # self.tableView.hideColumn(7)
        self.proxy_model.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp(self.searchcommands.text(), Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                                 QRegExp.FixedString))

        # search all columns
        self.proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)

        # enable sorting by columns
        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)

        # set editing disabled for my use
        # self.tableView.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableView.setWordWrap(True)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.command_description = QLabel()
        self.command_description.setWordWrap(True)
        # self.command_requires_label = QLabel("Command Requires:")
        # self.command_requires_label.setWordWrap(True)
        hLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        # hLayout.addWidget(self.command_requires_label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableView)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.searchcommands)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonCadastro)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.command_description)
        self.layout.addLayout(hLayout)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.resize(730, 600)

        self.searchcommands.textChanged.connect(self.searchcommands.update)
        self.searchcommands.textChanged.connect(self.proxy_model.setFilterRegExp)
        self.searchcommands.setText("")
        self.searchcommands.setPlaceholderText(u"buscar")

        # self.tableView.clicked.connect(self.listclicked)
        # self.startDate.dateChanged.connect(self.startDate.update)
        # self.startDate.dateChanged.connect(self.FilterBetweenDates)
        # self.endDate.dateChanged.connect(self.endDate.update)
        # self.endDate.dateChanged.connect(self.FilterBetweenDates)

        # Save Button

    def exportCadastro(self):
        with open('cadastro.csv', 'w') as stream:  # 'w'
                writer = csv.writer(stream, lineterminator='\n')
                for rowNumber in range(self.model.rowCount()):
                    fields = [
                        self.model.data(
                            # self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedRows()
                            self.model.index(rowNumber, columnNumber),
                            Qt.DisplayRole
                        )
                        for columnNumber in range(self.model.columnCount())
                    ]
                    print(fields)
                    writer.writerow(fields)

    def initializedModel(self):
        self.model.setTable("cadastro")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        # self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "instituicao")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "crianca")
        self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "data_de_nascimento")
        self.model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "manequim")
        self.model.setHeaderData(5, Qt.Horizontal, "calcado")
        self.model.setHeaderData(6, Qt.Horizontal, "responsavel")

    def onAddRow(self):
        self.model.insertRows(self.model.rowCount(), 1)
        self.model.submit()

    def onDeleteRow(self):
        self.model.removeRow(self.tableView.currentIndex().row())
        self.model.submit()
        self.model.select()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.db.close()

    # def listclicked(self, index):
    # row = index.row()
    # cmd = self.proxy_model.data(self.proxy_model.index(row, 3))
    # cmd_requires = self.proxy_model.data(self.proxy_model.index(row, 4))
    # cmd_description = self.proxy_model.data(self.proxy_model.index(row, 5))
    # print(cmd_description)
    # self.command_description.setText(cmd_description)
    # self.command_requires_label.setText('This command requires being executed via: ' + cmd_requires.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I did that, sorry about the mess but I'm still learning.

Comment: then read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: If you have an answer then post it as an answer in the answers section. Please read [answer]

Comment: Ok, thanks I did that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the selected rows:

```py
def exportCadastro(self):
    with open("cadastro.csv", "w") as stream:
        writer = csv.writer(stream, lineterminator="\n")
        for row in self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedRows():
            fields = []
            for col in range(self.tableView.model().columnCount()):
                field = self.tableView.model().index(row, col).data()
                fields.append(field)
            writer.writerow(fields)
```

Comment: I'm still having problem to interate with QSqlTableModel and QTableView. I reformulated my question